# How do we use sub query in hive using pyspark

Tags: python, hive

I am trying to use a Hive subquery in python but I see Unsupported Language feature message. Am I missing something in the code or are nested queries not supported using pyspark?

My Python Version is 2.6.6.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

###Establising Spark Hive connection
sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)



hv_qr = "select st.store_num, 'NULL' as st.store_type, st.prjt_type FROM dis_ingst.store_info st WHERE st.store_num NOT IN (select store_number FROM dis_ingst.store_combine WHERE prjt_type IN (\"MX\", \"CN\", \"UK\")) AND st.prjt_type IN (\"MX\", \"CN\", \"UK\") limit 10"

val = sqlContext.sql(hv_qr)
output = val.collect()
print output


Error:
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'\nUnsupported language features in query: select st.store_num, 'NULL' as st.store_type, st.prjt_type FROM dis_ingst.store_info st WHERE st.store_num NOT IN (select store_number FROM dis_ingst.store_combine WHERE prjt_type IN (\"MX\", \"CN\", \"UK\")) AND st.prjt_type IN (\"MX\", \"CN\", \"UK\") limit 10
```

Comment: i think issue is 'NULL"

Comment: for Null you can simply used `' '`.

Comment: ohh the problem is `(\"MX\", \"CN\", \"UK\"))` you can't used `""` because its break your query.

Comment: Query is working fine with 'NULL' and with (\"MX\", \"CN\", \"UK\"),  if I add only sub query as above it's failing.
Example: In below query I just removed sub-query instead I used values, it works fine with this.  
hv_qr = "select st.store_num, 'NULL' as st.store_type, st.prjt_type FROM dis_ingst.store_info st WHERE st.store_num NOT IN ('212','431') AND st.prjt_type IN (\"MX\", \"CN\", \"UK\") limit 10"